# Installing Ubuntu on NUC8I7HNK headless?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, intel-nuc

I'm interested in this device:
 https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc8i7hnk.html and want to install Ubuntu on it. I only need SSH access to it, and I'm probably not going to use it for desktop applications. Or does Ubuntu require X11 during installation?

The problem right now is that there's a video driver only available in the 4.18 kernel for the Radeon™ RX Vega M GL graphics card.

Do I need the driver if I only want to install Ubuntu on it in "text mode" or can I install it without the driver?

The video card is listed as "discrete". There is also an "integrated graphics" listed in the specs. Does this mean this device has two graphic cards, with one that Ubuntu can fall back on for non-graphical applications?

Comment: If you are not going to use it as a desktop machine, you can just install Ubuntu Server and never worry about video drivers.

Comment: That's good to know Jos!

Comment: I suppose that answers your question? Allow me to post this as an answer.

Comment: One further question: is it also possible to run a desktop environment on this without the driver? I don't need fancy graphical performance for gaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't plan on using the computer as a desktop machine, I would recommend installing Ubuntu Server. The server version of Ubuntu does not install video drivers (or anything X) out of the box.

Your system has a low-spec, but working, graphics subsystem on-board ("integrated") that will allow you to install Ubuntu Server from the installation media without any problems. On top of that, it has a second, separate, high-end video card ("discrete"). You don't need that to run Ubuntu Server, but it doesn't get in the way either. Typically, you enable / disable on-board graphics from the BIOS.

Should you, at a later time, decide you want to run a desktop environment, you just install `ubuntu-desktop`. This will come with X and install the necessary video drivers. That there is no separated video driver for your graphics card doesn't mean it doesn't work at all, only that some of the functionality may not be available. So perhaps wait until your system runs on Linux kernel 4.18 before you install a desktop environment if you want to be sure; if you don't game or edit videos, the card's "mostly working" will be enough.

Comment: I found out is the on-board video card is a Intel® HD Graphics 630 which is supposed to be supported in kernel 4.15 which is in Ubuntu 18.04. So I should already have reasonable desktop experience with this.